# return contents of class object attribute in javascript when called

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, javascript-objects

The best way I could describe this is to treat it like a pandas Series in python. For example if I were to create a Series class:

```
class Series{
    constructor(d){
        this._series = d;
    }

    std = () =>{
        return Statistics.std(this._series);
    }

    variance = () =>{
        
    }
    
}
```

I want to do something similar to in python were we have an array, arr, and create a series like so:

```
pandas_series = pd.Series(arr)
```

So when i do something like `console.log(pandas_series)` in JS.

Thanks, this will clear up a lot of missunderstanding I have. I am not too clear on the jargon so Im not totally clear on what to search

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, at least not to me. Are you asking for a JS implementation of pandas series?

Comment: so if i called, for example from what i illustrated above, the Series class i want to return just the contents of this._series, instead of the entire class object. Much like the pandas Series object, when I call a new series object after I have created it it just returns the values of the series. If that makes sense?

Comment: I think you're confusing how the object prints with the actual value of the object.

Comment: You can simply use `pd._series`. Or write a getter method that returns `this._series`. So this has nothing to do with python or panda actually?

Comment: @ChrisG No it doesnt. My question is, if i call pandas_series in js how can I get the data is this._series without actually printing the entire class object. Ill remove the pandas tag

Comment: @Barmar Likely. Is there a getter method that i can write that simply gives me back the value of a certain class parameter if I call the new object created?

Comment: You can define the `.valueOf()` method.